# Fix Automapper OData for getting a single result back

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, automapper

I have the issue where after setting up Automapper.Extensions.OData my getbyid is returning null for all values. My GetOrdersAsync works fine (both expanding and non expanding calls, everything is returned that I need)

**Repositories:**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<OrderDto>> GetOrdersAsync(ODataQueryOptions<OrderDto> options)
{
    return await _context.Orders.GetQueryAsync(_mapper, options);
}

public async Task<OrderDto?> GetOrderByIdMapperAsync(int id)
{
    return await _context.Orders
        .Where(x => x.Id == id)
        .ProjectTo<OrderDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

**Automapper**

```
CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.ExplicitExpansion());
```

**Controllers**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<OrderDto>>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<OrderDto> options)
{
    var orders = await _orderRepository.GetOrdersAsync(options);
    return Ok(orders);
}

[EnableQuery]
public async Task<ActionResult<OrderDto?>> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return await _orderRepository.GetOrderByIdMapperAsync(key);
}
```

**DTO**

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public string? CategoryName { get; set; } // this is a separate entity (navigation)
    public OrderStatusDto? OrderStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I haven't updated the repository for the GetOrderByIdMapperAsync, whenever I try to do something like GetQueryAsync it will return a syntax error, unsure how to perform it even after looking at documentation. Can I pass the options to it as well? (I tried this but again not sure how it combines with SingleOrDefaultAsync)

Answer (score 0):

If in both the "Order" and "OrderDto" classes the properties are the same, you should have no problems with the mapping. An alternative I suggest is to use the ReverseMap method.
Your code would look like this:

**Automapper**

```
CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>().ReverseMap();
```

With this you can map in both directions without problems.

Comment: That helps fix the issue for nulls occurring in getting orderbyid, however two issues arise:

1. My DB queries are not optimised since it makes calls to navigation properties I haven't expanded (this also occurs in the GetOrdersAsync method) - whereas without the reversemap, it queries depending on my request (expanded vs not exapnded).

Comment: Ok, in that case if you are trying to map properties that you don't have in the DTO for example, maybe you should consider two options: 1) have the properties that you know you need in the query exactly the same as their "Order" origin and avoid errors. 2) "the less efficient" to do a direct property x property mapping if you want it.

Comment: Have you thought about changing your GetOrderByIdMapperAsync method ? 
like this: 
for example, make use of IMapper like this: 
private readonly IMapper _mapper; 
    constructorName (IMapper mapper){
    _mapper = mapper;
    }
public async Task<OrderDto?> GetOrderByIdMapperAsync(int id)
{   
var findOrder = await _context.Orders.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id); //option 1.
var findOrder = await _context.Orders.FindAsync(id);//option 2
var orderDto = _mapper.Map<OrderDto>(findOrder);
return orderDto;
}